# Как правильно передавать данные между Activity?

Tags: java, android

Сейчас я использую такой способ передачи:

```
Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, DegSet.class);
    intent.putExtra("TypeDeg", FLAG_GET_TIME);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FLAG_GET_TIME);
```

Потом достаю их:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    _typedeg = intent.getIntExtra("TypeDeg", 0);
```

Но где-то увидел, что этот способ устарел и чем-то опасен в плане потери передаваемых данных.
Вопрос: действительно ли такой способ устарел и опасен? Тогда, как правильно?

Comment: Не устарел, безопасен. Так и правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать статический метод в классе DegSet, в который в качестве параметров будет передаваться **FLAG_GET_TIME**.

Тогда литерал **"TypeDeg"** можно инкапсулировать в константу в классе DegSet. Благодаря этому, классы, которые будут работать с DegSet, не обязаны знать с каким именно именем надо класть **FLAG_GET_TIME**, что поможет избежать ошибок в случае неправильного ввода имени (например, "Typedeg", вместо "TypeDeg").

Пример реализации:

**Класс DegSet**

```
private static final String EXTRA_FLAG_GET_TIME = "TypeDeg";

public static Intent newIntent(Context context, int flagGetTime) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DegSet.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FLAG_GET_TIME, flagGetTime);
    return intent;
}
```

**Получение EXTRA в DegSet**

Получение extra почти не изменилось, вместо литерала теперь стоит константа

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
_typedeg = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_FLAG_GET_TIME, 0);
```

**Класс, использующий DegSet**

```
Intent intent = DegSet.newIntent(this, FLAG_GET_TIME);
startActivityForResult(intent, FLAG_GET_TIME);
```

Comment: и в чем смысл подобной конструкции?

Comment: @rjhdby смысл в том, что нам не надо помнить, что надо ввести именно "TypeDeg". И, если нам вдруг захочется изменить "TypeDeg" на что-то другое, то мы сделаем это в одном месте, вместо того, чтобы изменять в нескольких местах в разных классах.